# Overlaying DIVs are destroying imagemaps, HELP!

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a small problem. To keep it short, I have a container div and a div that rotates out images as well as image maps of clickable links within each image, like a gallery with navigation built into the images themselves. Recently, I was asked to get some simple animation overlayed onto the image/divs. I used jsAnim to accomplish this...and succeeded, but now the imagemap links in the original, containing div are no longer working.

The code works something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="testanim" style="z-index:2; width:50; height:50;"><a href="#"><img src="test.png" ></a></div>
    <div id="fadeshow"></div>
</div>
```

We have some Javascript used to rotate out images/imagemaps for fadeshow, and testanim is a small image overlayed on top of the fadeshow, but now the imagemaps do not work. I was very excited to get the animation working but now I have this bug to deal with. Can anyone assist me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way around this. You are essentially "covering up" an element with another element.

The only thing I can think of is to rely on event bubbling (bind a click event to the fadeshow). You'd probably need some fairly complex logic to determine if the coordinates clicked are within a range specified by the imagemap.